# .NET Inheritance : Returning an instance of a class which implements a given interface from a MusiInherit/abstract function

Tags: .net, inheritance, abstract-class, return-type

I have a base class which contains an abstract/MustInherit method.  I  want this method to return an instance of a class which implements a given interface.

When I come to implement the method in the derived class, I get a compiler error because the return types do not match (ie. in the abstract class, the return type is that of the interface, whereas in the derived class the return type is the class which implements the interface).

Can anyone clarify the underlying problem for me?  I can't quite get my head around what's wrong.  Especially given that the specified return type of the abstract method is an interface, which can't be instantiated, so surely the method implementation must return an instance of class which implements the interface? Maybe I just can't see the wood for the trees.

I can code around the issue by making the base class generic (and I can specify that T must implement my interface), then the abstract method would return an instance of T.  I'm not sure about that solution though.  It seems a bit of a hack, I don't get why I can't do it with straight inheritance.

Comment: Can you post the code please? These questions are much clearer with code in front of us.

Comment: On a side note, I've used your generic base class approach before, though it gets a bit awkward when you want to work with the base class in your code.  I would usually end up creating a non-generic base interface with an explicit implementation in the base to expose the 'most general' form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could accomplish what you're after:

```
public interface ISomething {}
public class Something : ISomething {}

public abstract class Base
{
    public ISomething Method()
    {
        return DoMethod();
    }

    protected abstract ISomething DoMethod();
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public new Something Method()
    {
        return (Something) DoMethod();
    }

    protected override ISomething DoMethod()
    {
        return null; //derived logic here
    }
}
```

The issue is that overridden methods are constrained to have the exact same signature as their base.  Suppose you were to create a value type that implements `ISomething` and then specialized the override in Derived to return the value type.  Now the overridden method is returning a value type that implements the interface, but, calling the method from the Base, you would expect to get a *boxed* value type of the form of the interface.  If the Derived call returned an unboxed value when calling through the Base, the calling code would try to access it as if it were already boxed, causing a failure.

Comment: This is what I am going to go with.  You've explained the underlying issue well.  I knew I could return an instance of the derived class from a method with the return type of the base class, but I was thinking I'd end up casting it to the derived type all over the place, but you've covered that off nicely too.  Cheers.

Comment: @Gavin, It's worth noting that IL (not merely C#) has verifiable strong-typing.  In principle, you could get around this restriction with some compiler support (i.e. implement the method internally as the base signature, but automatically Emit cast or Box/Unbox instructions when calling the overridden method through the derived type.)  If you asked Mr. Lippert why it's not supported, I'm guessing he'd say the value added by the feature wouldn't justify the effort to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

The way I envision your code now is that you have an abstract base class containing a method (`GetFruit`) that returns an interface that I'll call `IFruit`. In a derived class, you want to be able to return (from this same `GetFruit` method) an `Apple` object that implements the `IFruit` interface.

However, as convenient as that might be, **the Common Language Specification (CLS) does not allow compliant languages to support *return type covariance***. This includes all of the .NET languages, like VB.NET and C#. There is a lot of misinformation that exists on exactly why this limitation arises and what exactly is responsible for this limitation, but the simple answer is that you cannot narrow the return type on a method in a derived class to a more specific derivation.

That means that even though `Apple` implements `IFruit`, you cannot type the method in a derived class to return `Apple`. The overridden methods must have the same return value signature as that of their base. **So, instead, each method must return an object of the same type** (`IFruit`) **for all classes that derive from your base class.** Simply changing the return value of the method in your derived class to be the same type as the method in the base class will solve your problem.

You mention the possibility of making the base class generic, and while this would probably work, it seems to introduce unnecessary complexity. Using my contrived example above, since an `Apple` fully implements the `IFruit` interface, you should get the full benefit of type checking and even Intellisense by simply returning `IFruit` from your derived classes.

**EDIT:** If you're open to something a little bit hack-ish, you can always re-declare the method in your derived class (by marking it as `new` or `Shadows`). This will allow you to return whatever type of object that you want, regardless of the signature of the method in the base class. However, remember that there is no way to re-declare and override a method at the same time, so you're not truly polymorphic.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems like you have something like this:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public abstract ISomeInterface Get();
}

public class Sub : Base
{
    public override SomeInterfaceImpl Get() { .. }
}
```

The solution is to keep the return type from the base class i.e:

```
public override ISomeInterface Get()
{
    return new SomeInterfaceImpl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your method's return type in the derived class the interface.

Example:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract IInterface YourMethod();
}

class Derived
{
    public override IInterface YourMethod()
    {
        return new TypeThatImplementsIInterface();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the return type of an overloaded method in a derived class. Neither in C#, nor in C++, nor in VB.NET. Leave it as it is, and you can return an instance of class which implements the interface.

The reason: abstract methods are intended to be used in abstract algorithms that work only on the common interface of different derived classes. What you have described is just the case of an abstract factory. You will find a detailed explanation here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern